# SUM Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I have a table in `SQL Server`, and I need to sum a column, like the example below:

```
CREATE TABLE B
(
ID int,
Qty int,
)

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,2)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2,7)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO B VALUES (4,11)

SELECT *, '' AS TotalQty FROM B
ORDER BY ID
```

In this example what I need is the column `TotalQty` give me the values like:

```
 2
 9
 11
 22
```

How can it be achieved?

Comment: you are looking for running total in sql server

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa67a/2  your answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SUM` in  a co-related subquery  or `CROSS APPLY` like this

**Co-related Subquery**

```
SELECT ID,(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM B WHERE B.id <= C.id) FROM B as C
ORDER BY ID
```

**Using `CROSS APPLY`**

```
SELECT ID,D.Qty FROM B as C
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT SUM(Qty) Qty 
FROM B WHERE B.id <= C.id
)AS D
ORDER BY ID
```

**Output**

```
1   2
2   9
3   11
4   22
```

If you were using SQL Server 2012 or above, `SUM()` with `Over()` clause could have been used like this.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Qty) OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) FROM B as C
ORDER BY ID
```

**Edit**

Another way to do this in SQL Server 2008 is using Recursive CTE. Something like this.

***Note:** This method is based on the answer by [Roman Pekar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744834/roman-pekar) on this thread [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver). Based on his observation this would perform better than co related subquery and `CROSS APPLY` both*

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT ID,Qty,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) as rn 
FROM B
), CTE_Running_Total as 
(
    SELECT Id,rn,Qty,Qty as Running_Total 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT C1.Id,C1.rn,C1.Qty,C1.Qty + C2.Running_Total as Running_Total
    FROM CTE C1 
    INNER JOIN CTE_Running_Total C2
    ON C1.rn = C2.rn + 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_Running_Total
ORDER BY Id
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: i just thinking same and u posted answer .. :)..
but it slower if amount of data is too large..

Comment: @AnantDabhi - Yes you are correct. for large sets of data this will be slow. `SUM()` with `over(order by id asc)`  could have been used however this is only supported in sql 2012

Comment: "will it work for more than 10 million records". Yes it will. Will it be fast is based on your requirements, table and index structure.